# load driver with insmode get :disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, arm

I compiled simple drive for Linux kernel for ARM system:

> $ uname -a

```
Linux CR5 4.4.171-cr5 #2 Tue Mar 10 11:49:00 CET 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

To compile i used the config file from the up ruining system located at:

> /proc/config.gz

i downloaded a vanilla kernel, checkout to tag 4.4.5, replace the config file ,compile the kernel, and then compile the drive with the tool-chine for arm

> gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_arm-linux-gnueabi
> The drive contain simple code

```
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>

    int init_module(void) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    void cleanup_module(void) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world.\n");
    }
```

i used *insmod* to load the driver but the err message to terminal is:

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module test_module.ko: Invalid module format

at the *dmesg* i get this message

> test_module: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

However, when i compere between running module in the system with my module with *readelf -a*

The **ELF Header** are the same and the **File Attributes** are the same.

what can i check more?
Maybe the module loading was blocked by kernel? how can i check that?
some one hes a lead for my what i can do next?

p.s

- simple c program is ruining fine, so i guess the tool-chine is fine
- *insmod -f*  not work as well

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem was at the layout , even all the same same layout was changed

found answer here

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720177/module-layout-version-incompatibility)